# How to use jquery to check response header when the page render

Tags: header, response

Is it possible to check the response header inside $(document).ready function? In one of our java apps, a filter is placed in front of some html pages, the filter is used to determine whether certian action should be taken by seting the response header info. I need to know that piece of information right away after the user click a link to come to this html page.